# Is it possible to generate the artifact.xml and content.xml without using tycho plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi, tycho, p2

I am searching for a way to generate the `artifact.xml` and the `content.xml` manually without using the `eclipse tycho-plugin`. Currently I have all the OSGi bundles and the features(with all the dependant bundles) to be installed in to the `p2-repo` in a seperate location. By looking at the content of the `artifact.xml` and `content.xml`  files, I observed that they contain most of the meta data available in the existing bundles and features plus few additional meta data. Is it possible to generate the above two files without using the `Tycho plugin`.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Might the Eclipse *Features and Bundles Publisher* be what you are looking for?

Eclipse brings with it some helper applications that can be run on the command line. One of it is the *Features and Bundles Publisher*. From the documentation:

> The features and bundles publisher application (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher) is a command line application that is capable of generating metadata (p2 repositories) from pre-built Eclipse bundles and features.

You can find more information including sample calls in the [respective Eclipse documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fp2_publisher.html).

Comment: it uses `eclipse tycho plugin` internally and currently I am using it. I need a way to generate those two files manually without using `eclipse tycho plugin`. In other words I need a way to update features and bundles on a system where `java` isn't available and installing `java` is not an option

Comment: Well, I don't think that Eclipse is using Tycho here (the p2 stuff existed in Eclipse before there was Tycho), but doesn't matter if you have this requirement. If you can't use Java then you should mention that explicitly in your question. I don't know of any non-Java p2 tool.